# jQuery- changing colour of nav bar at certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have this working on each webpage, other than my 'about us' page. 
Basically, I have used the variable:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
<p id="startchange">
```

which links to the JQuery to initiate the change in colour / replacing the image with the other one. Currently neither of these attributes are changing, however on other pages they work just fine: as the `sticky nav bar` becomes smaller using waypoints. I am using these variables pretty early in my code (Just underneath header).

It seems no matter where I place these, they do not seem to execute, and I am not sure why.

jQuery:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#startchange');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('#navbar').css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
          $("#navbar img").attr("src", "images/logo-grey-real.jpg");
       } else {
          $('#navbar').css('background-color', '#fff');
          $("#navbar img").attr("src", "images/logo.jpg");
       }
   });
});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw02qx6m/) :)

**HTML :**

```
<div class="navbar"></div>
<p id="test">test</p>
```

**Jquery :**

```
var offset = $('#test').offset().top;
var navbar = $('.navbar');

$(document).scroll(function() {
    position = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (position < offset)
        navbar.css('background-color', 'red');
    else
        navbar.css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```